# Consul Snapshot errors

Tags: snapshot, consul

We are getting the below error when trying to save snapshots in Consul Open source version. Our version details are below.

We tried this both from the leader and follower nodes. We haven't restored any consul servers recently.
Only thing we did was the regular maintenance (i.e. applying OS patches) + deleting the **raft.db** as it was grown above 90 GB and restarting the consul services.

As of now the services are running fine and the only issue is we couldn't snapshot them on a regular basis for recovery purposes.

One other thing is the snapshots reference directory # from below output - **5-80085657-1602164735964** changes with every execution and hence we couldn't create directory manually as well.

````
Consul v1.2.2
Protocol 2 spoken by default, understands 2 to 3 (agent will automatically use protocol >2 when speaking to compatible agents)```

```root@srv1:/srv/consul/raft# consul snapshot save -token=***** test.snap
Error saving snapshot: Unexpected response code: 500 (failed to open snapshot: open /srv/consul/raft/snapshots/5-80085657-1602164735964/meta.json: no such file or directory:)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The raft/snapshots directory under the [data_dir](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_data_dir) (i.e., /srv/consul) is meant to be used by the Consul server agent to periodically write the raft log to disk (see [`raft_snapshot_threshold`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_raft_snapshot_threshold) and [`raft_snapshot_interval`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_raft_snapshot_interval)).

Per this knowledge base article https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047813374-Consul-raft-snapshot-directory-full-of-tmp-directories you should use a different directory to take backups of Consul using `consul snapshot save`. Try saving the snapshot in an alternate directory like /root or your home directory, and see if that resolves the error.

Comment: Hello @Blake, I did attempted to use different directories but it failed with the same error as shown below,  ```root@srv1:~# consul snapshot save -http-addr=localhost:8500 -token=**** /tmp/test.snap         
Error saving snapshot: Unexpected response code: 500 (failed to open snapshot: open /srv/consul/raft/snapshots/5-80178631-1602242717241/meta.json: no such file or directory:)```